# Using an Apple iCloud account on Windows Phone 8

Tags: 8.0, accounts

My iPhone died, and I am looking to replace it with a more budget model until such time as I have the relevant funds to justify an expensive handset.  I'm looking at a Lumia 520, which comes in at around 20% the price of an iPhone 5.

A lot of the time to be honest I only intend to use it like an old feature phone for dumb calls and texts, the main feature being WiFi hotspot for my iPad.  But it's important for me to be able to use my genuine Contacts and Calendars properly on the device, and these are all held on an iCloud account.  Exporting and importing is not an option, as I have a relatively complex system of delegation going on with family members that relies on iCloud to work.

So my question is, is iCloud supported on Win Phone 8?  Either as a top level choosable account type, or as a manual entry, and will it enable me to have access to multiple calendars that I can choose to put events into?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iCloud contacts and calendars are not supported on Windows Phone 8.

The next update to Windows Phone 8, "Amber", is said to feature CalDAV and CardDAV support. This should enable syncing contacts and calendars with iCloud on a Windows Phone 8. Amber is expected to arrive in August 2013.

Answer (score 0):

Try these instructions, they worked for me, but for my iCloud Calendar showing 6 hours off on the Windows Phone.

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2478215

> 1. Go to Settings --> email +accounts --> and click "add an account"
> 2. Select "Google"
> 3. When prompted, enter a valid Gmail address and password. (we will fix this later)
> 4. Wait patiently for the initial sync to finish..(It may take up to 5 mins)
> 5. Locate the account that you created and tap on it to open the account settings...(It will be called Google, Google 2, etc).
> 6. Change the "Account Name" to something meaningful (I changed mine to iCloud)
> 7. Change the email address to the one you use for iCloud. *NOTE* If you don't use iCloud mail, enter a dummy email address here that is
>      different from any other email address already on the device.
> 8. Set "download new content" to a value that you prefer. (Mine is set to every 15 mins)
> 9. Set "Download email from" to an appropriate value.
> 10. in the "content to sync" section, check which iCloud info you want to sync. (Email, Contacts, or Calendar)
> 11. in the "Your Name" field, enter your name.
> 12. If you will be using IMAP to sync with iCloud email, change the Incoming email server to "imap.mail.me.com:993", if not skip this
>       step.
> 13. for the User Name, enter your iCloud user name. (Mine is my apple id because I never made an iCloud email account)
> 14. for the password enter your password.
> 15. If you will be using IMAP to sync with iCloud email, change the Outgoing email server to "smtp.mail.me.com:587", if not skip this
>       step.
> 16. If you will be using IMAP to sync with iCloud email, make sure "Outgoing server requires authentication" is checked, if not skip this
>       step.
> 17. For the "Contacts server (CardDAV)" enter "contacts.icloud.com".
> 18. for Calendar server (CalDAV)" enter "caldav.icloud.com".
> 19. Click the "Check" box to save your settings.
> 20. Check to see if things are syncing!
>       *NOTE* If the calendar sync is not working, it may be necessary to change you CalDAV server name to p0#-caldav.icloud.com, where # is
>       represents the numbers 1-9. Example: p05-caldav.icloud.com or
>       p04-caldav.icloud.com). If you don't want to experiment, there are
>       instructions online on how to pull the right server name from Apple's
>       Calendar app.
>
> **EDIT** More Info on Time Zones:
>
> 1. When The Windows Phone sends the info about the event to the CalDav Server, the phone tells iCloud the event is in "Eastern Standard
>      Time". (It should be "Eastern Direct Time" bc DST.) When the CalDAV
>      Server correctly sends this data back to the phone, the phone
>      processes as "Eastern Standard Time" and "bumps" the event forward an
>      hour. The phone also doesn't send all the proper TimeZone info back to
>      the server in the ICS file, resulting in a non-editable event in the
>      iCloud calendar. If you Switch the displayed time zone from "Eastern
>      Standard Time" to "Eastern Time" in the iCloud Calendar app, you can
>      edit the event. When it comes back to the phone, it will be off by 4
>      hours due to the processing bug (see 2)
> 2. CalDAV entries that are created in iCloud come back to the device with a time zone of "US/Eastern". I am guessing there is a parsing bug
>      in the app so that when it sees the "/", it freaks out, stops
>      processing the TimeZone data contained in the ics file, and leaves the
>      entry as GMT.
>
> A couple of ways that may fix the TimeZone issue with the calendars:
>   1. Turn on TimeZone Support vial iCloud.com or the Calendar app. Make all your entries in the "Floating" time zone. This forces all calendar
>   entries to be set with the "Real" time on the server and strips out
>   TimeZone calculation.